# Passing variable in params hash through link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameters

I have a link like this:

```
<%= link_to "up", "/results/#{@search}" %>
```

If I were using a named route, I know I could do this:

```
<%= link_to "up", up_path(:type => "variable") %>
```

but since I'm not using a named route, how could I pass in a variable into the params hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the regular way of getting variables in there:

```
/results/?var1=value&var2=value2
```

etc

so in your link

```
<%= link_to "up", "/results/?type=#{@search}" %>
```

of course it may not be the best of practices but you can start there